# Firebase Auth error : Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, authentication

I have this repo

[Github simple repo](https://github.com/HosMercury/start-firebase-auth)

I just want to **connect to firebase to express without using React** ..
I got this error

```
Error: Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.
```

Comment: Couple of things. First of all, it's typically a bad idea to push keys up to Github where they can be seen. You might look into using environmental variables, [here's a good primer](https://www.twilio.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js-html). Secondly, the first step i would recommend is trying to copy & paste the API keys again like the error suggests. I think using Firebase you should certainly be able to do this, nothing about Express precludes it.

Comment: I had changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a video for figuring out what i learned

[Youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/qPAkP42I92o)